# how to do a simple subquery in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

Anyone know how I can do a very simple/basic subquery in LINQ like so:

```
SELECT a.VendorID,a.Name,
  (SELECT count(Agency_Code) from Contracts b where b.Vendor_Code = a.VendorID)
```

FROM Vendors a

just trying to get a count of the number of contracts each vendor has

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = vendors.Select(v => new
    { 
        v.VendorId,
        v.Name,
        CountOfAgencyCodes = contracts.Where(c => c.VendorCode == v.VendorId).Count()
    });
```